# Extracting first letter of a name and the entire last name

Tags: regex

I need to use Regex to get the first letter of a user's first name and also the entire last name. What I currently have works well for users who have two names, but the code does not work when a third name is included.

This is what I currently have: `^(.)[^ ]* (\w+)$`

Works for:

- Tom Jones → TJones.

Doesn't work for:

- Tom Smith Jones. It should return TJones.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to exclude any special characters in the last name - it should just be alphabetical characters.

UPDATE: found this code in a different post (\w).*(\s+\w+)$

that code manages to get the first character and last word but does not remove the space.

Example: Tom Mike Andrew Jones -> T Jones instead of TJones.

I then updated that to be (\w).*(\s+)(\w+)$ and that works flawlessly. Now i'm left with figuring out how to ignore special characters for last names like Pierre-Louis for example.

Any of you regex experts know a way to ignore the special characters?

Comment: Why are you only considering a regex-based solution?  Passing the names as parameters to a bash script, for example, could be equally feasible.  The script would see the components of the name as variables $1 $2 $3 etc., and you can easily pick off the first letter of $1 and the entire value of $N, where N is the number of parameters the script receives.  `man bash` and then search for `:offset:length`.  As for removing undesired characters, `sed` or `tr` are your friends.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm working in Nintex and what the regex code would do is take the Name that is entered in the form, store the results in a variable, And then that variable is referenced in a Create AD User action later on in the workflow. I can look further into running a script like you suggested and see if i have any luck with that in Nintex.

Comment: My personal favorites in this situation might be `cat` `awk`, and `sed`. `cat ./FILE | awk '{print $1 $2;}' | ...`

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/BGLa6y/1) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the regex to the following,

```
(\w).*\W+(\w+)$
```

instead of `\s` user `\W` (uppercase W) which matches any nonword characters.